# Polar to Cartesian- Why are they slightly different?

Tags: trigonometry, polar-coordinates

When I make a polar equation, lets say `r=θ`, I can convert  it to cartesian / rectangular with:
`y=cos(t)*t, x=sin(t)*t` implying that t is from 0 to a number.

I plug this into my grapher, and the results:
[image]

They both seem to work as expected, *from this view.*

 I zoomed into the graph, and they seem to be slightly apart. Is this because of my computer's processing power, or because of mathematics itself? Any reasoning would be great. Also, I am wondering why they are different.
EDIT: Still want to know how both of them are processed on the computer side, leading to different results. Thanks!

Comment: Likely due to your computer.  Nothing is wrong with the math here.

Comment: Thanks. Just tested on a more powerful computer and results are the same- Will answer my own question

Comment: Cool.  :-)  May help for you to figure out **why** the math works while your at it.

Answer (score 1):

*Self-Answered*

It was my computer, the processor most likely limited out at a certain float. I tested on a more powerful computer and the results are the same. I'm still wondering why they were *different*, though.

Comment: is *powerful* synonym of *more digits* ? does it relate to the HW or the SW you are using ?

Comment: By this comment, yes, _powerful_ is a synonym of _more digits_ meaning more exact. And the software was the same- just a 2008 Mac versus a 2016 Mac